# Issue with understanding the difference in efficiency in two Scala functions - Recursive union

Tags: scala, union

I'm taking a course in Scala and I can't understand the difference in efficiency between two functions. This course is about Binary Search Trees which contains tweets described as TweetSets and is is specifically the union function that confuses me.

I understand that the first one decomposes the tree and adds the element into that through the incl function but I can't see why the second is better. Isn't the tree fully broken down in both cases?

A tree can be described as:

```
class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet:
```

These are the two union functions:

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = left.union(right).union(that).incl(elem)
```

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = left.union(right.union(that).incl(elem))
```

They both terminate thanks to the function union in the Empty Set:

```
def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = that
```

I know that the second function is more efficient as it passed the tests while the first one didn't.

Edit: I should add some code to further explain the classes. I'll past them below.

This is for the empty set:

```
class Empty extends TweetSet:

  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = that
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = acc

  def mostRetweeted: Tweet = throw java.util.NoSuchElementException()
  def helper(most: Tweet) = most

  def descendingByRetweet: TweetList = Nil

  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  def contains(tweet: Tweet): Boolean = false

  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = NonEmpty(tweet, Empty(), Empty())

  def remove(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = this

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = ()
```

And this is the NonEmpty:

```
class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet:

  def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = left.union(right.union(that).incl(elem))
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet =
    if p(this.elem) then left.union(right).filterAcc(p, acc.incl(this.elem))
    else left.union(right).filterAcc(p, acc)


  def mostRetweeted: Tweet = helper(this.elem)
  
  def helper(most: Tweet): Tweet = 
    if this.elem.retweets > most.retweets then left.union(right).helper(elem)
    else left.union(right).helper(most)

  
  def descendingByRetweet: TweetList = Cons(this.mostRetweeted, this.remove(this.mostRetweeted).descendingByRetweet)


  /**
   * The following methods are already implemented
   */

  def contains(x: Tweet): Boolean =
    if x.text < elem.text then
      left.contains(x)
    else if elem.text < x.text then
      right.contains(x)
    else true

  def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet =
    if x.text < elem.text then
      NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if elem.text < x.text then
      NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else
      this

  def remove(tw: Tweet): TweetSet =
    if tw.text < elem.text then
      NonEmpty(elem, left.remove(tw), right)
    else if elem.text < tw.text then
      NonEmpty(elem, left, right.remove(tw))
    else
      left.union(right)

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit =
    f(elem)
    left.foreach(f)
    right.foreach(f)
```

As for the test, the first implementation did not finish as it took to long. The second union method that I posted in the beginning finished instantly.

Comment: Please share the complete code if you expect us to help you. We're missing some methods and classes to get the complete picture.

Comment: Also you mention one implementation doesn't pass the tests. Meaning the result is not the expected one? Or it doesn't end? Or it uses too much resources?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to fully understand without seeing the full code. However, I think you're basically correct that the tree is broken down entirely in both cases.

I would approach this using a simple example and writing out the recursion. Try TweetSet A, with A.left = B and A.right = C, and then an empty TweetSet S. (I'll let the A.elem = 'a', B.elem = 'b', etc.)

Then we evaluate A.union(S) for both the first and second algorithms.

```
A.union(S)
= B.union(C).union(S).incl('a')
= 0.union(0).union(C).incl('b').union(S).incl('a')
= C.incl('b').union(S).incl('a')
```

I'll admit, I'm not 100% sure how to evaluate this, since we don't have code for the TweetSet incl function. But what we can see is that we now have to alternate between inclusions and unions. For larger trees this will become exaggerated.

Second algorithm now.

```
A.union(S) 
= B.union(C.union(S).incl('a'))
= 0.union(0.union(C.union(S).incl('a')).incl('b'))
= C.union(S).incl('a').incl('b')
= 0.union(0.union(S).incl('a').incl('b').incl('c'))
= S.incl('a').incl('b').incl('c')
```

It's hard to see from just the algorithm statement, but this recursion puts all the unions together at the front, where they can be evaluated, while stacking the inclusions at the end.

Typically writing out a small example (or several) will be helpful in understanding why code is giving different performance or even different answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`left` is less than `elem`, `right` is greater. When you do `union` you pull `left`, `elem`, and `right` apart. You have no idea what's in `that`.
`left` and `right` are tidy little groups that you know go on either side of `elem`. Now why would you want to go do a messy thing like `left.union(right)`? You know you're going to have to put `elem` back in there at some point. Imagine `that` was empty. You've just shaken the tree all up while smushing `left` and `right` together, now you've got to shake it all up again to get `elem` back in there when you finally `incl`.

It's the same thing when `that` is not empty.